# I'm having trouble with make command for obs browser plugin

Tags: plugins, makefile, github, obs-studio

So I found on Obs forums this browser plugin which's on github https://github.com/bazukas/obs-qtwebkit
I'm a bit new to Ubuntu so I may be doing something wrong. But I downloaded the zip went to files>downloads and pressed extract here.
Then I went to terminal typed in
 `make '/home/nate/Downloads/obs-qtwebkit-master'`

but it returned

```
make: Nothing to be done for '/home/nate/Downloads/obs-qtwebkit-master'.
```

So I checked the readme file and it said

> "You may need to set `OBS_INCLUDE` and `OBS_LIB` env variables (see
>   Makefile)."

Which I have no idea what it means, please can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions say

> "Run `make` in the obs-qtwebkit directory to build the plugin."

If you unpacked the archive in `/home/nate/Downloads/obs-qtwebkit-master`, that translates to

```
cd /home/nate/Downloads/obs-qtwebkit-master/obs-qtwebkit
make
```

rather than

```
make '/home/nate/Downloads/obs-qtwebkit-master'
```